# Docker Mysql 8, Docker spring boot - Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: java, mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have been researching all possible permutations, but it didn't work out.

->application.properties

```
## DATASOURCE
#local connection
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Apple?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
# docker network connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb_container:3306/Apple?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

->build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE';
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}; group 'org.example'; version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'; sourceCompatibility = 1.8; repositories { mavenCentral() }; dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java'); testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

->Dockerfile

```
From openjdk:8
copy build/libs/Java_Mysql_Docker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar java_mysql_docker_jar.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","java_mysql_docker_jar.jar"]
```

->docker commands

```
docker network create java_mysql_docker_network
docker container run --name mysqldb_container --network java_mysql_docker_network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=Apple -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:8
gradle clean build
docker build -t java_mysql_docker_image .
docker container run --name java_mysql_docker_image_container --network java_mysql_docker_network -p 8080:8080 java_mysql_docker_image
```

->Exception Description:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

same application working fine for locally installed MySQL 8 for below URL

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Apple?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
```

but fails for Docker MySQL 8

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb_container:3306/Apple?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754319/docker-spring-boot-application-cannot-access-mysql-server-on-localhost?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that.

```
# This driver is not in the classpath.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


# Spring auto-detects the driver based on the JDBC URL. This one. 
# Explicitly setting the driver that is in the class path.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The error you are seeing, is form this class, from spring-boot project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceBeanCreationFailureAnalyzer.java

## Spring Doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html

Answer (score 0):

apparently commenting Driver works for both locally installed and docker MySQL 8.

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

but still would like to have an explanation why it does.